# Generate key in Java & C# common for both languages

Tags: c#, java

I want to generate key algorithm with 16 character. That algorithm method should be able to use in two language(Java & C#)?

In java I used `UUID`.That is not available in C#.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you could use the [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) class and more specifically the [NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) static method if you want to generate a new one.

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: I need common method.That should be available in java & C#

Comment: In Java it would be UUID.randomUUID()